# I'm trying to find out who makes this shiner bock mountain bike the serial number is TPT101202371

Tags: mountain-bike

TPT101202371 
This is the serial number on bottom of bicycle

Comment: Serial numbers are generally useless for bike identification.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. It is nearly impossible to identify a bicycle without pictures. Please [edit] some into your question. Once you do so, the question will automatically be flagged for reopening. You can find out more about how our site works by taking our [tour](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 5):

ANSWER: "Roland" and probably dating from 2005-2006.

```
The serial number was no use at all in this research.
Instead, the unusual and unique name, combined with the description was sufficient.
```

Apparently "Shiner Bock" is a brand of beer, and they don't make bikes.  You're looking at a promotional bicycle.  Here's a description found.

> Shiner Bock produced to support the LiveStrong foundation. Only 300 were produced. They were used in displays in stores. Has all Shimano hardware, like shifters, gears, brakes, etc. Omni shock front forks. Has Shiner Bock logo on drop bar, "Brewed with an attitude" on top bar, and the signature ram on the front.

[image]

The bike has nothing to do with the annual [Shiner GASP](https://www.shiner.com/connect/shiner-gasp) 100 mile mostly-road ride.

---

The bike pre-dates January 2007, based on https://www.flickr.com/photos/blondeamazon/359107170/in/photostream/

Further relevant photos from that stream:

[image]  You can clearly read the maker's name "ROLAND" on the chain stay.

[image]

[image]

[image] Front suspension has boots on the stanchions.  Clearly indicative of a 90s or early 2000s MTB.  OMNI forks are not exactly high-end.

[image]

[image]

---

Looks like the Livestrong foundation and Shiner Beer were connected for the 2006 year, according to https://www.bizjournals.com/austin/stories/2006/04/17/tidbits1.html and in 2009 that Texan took a sponsorship deal from Michelob, a Belgian brewer.